# XAML string formatting in windows phone

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How i can format DateTime in the given format (7/24/13, 11:24 AM), I found an option to format  the string in similar manner **[Text="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat={0:g}}"]**, But I cannot add (",") comma in between date and time. How i can do this in windows phone. Currently with the string format i am getting the date like this (7/24/13 11:24 AM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy, h:mm tt}'}" />
```

will give you

08/22/2013, 11:52 AM